# youtube data api v3 404 (not found)

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to learn how to work with YouTube API and it gave me this 404 (not found) error.

This is my code:

```
fetch("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCVSUF_SaDCLze2KiVrNkmrw&maxResults=10&order=date&key=AIzaSy...")
.then((result)=>{
    return result.json()
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
    let videos = data.items
    let container = document.querySelector(".youtube-container")
    for(video of videos)
    {
        container.innerHTML += '<img src="${video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}">'
    }
})
```

anyone know what is the problem?
im working with vscode if its important

i tried to run this code and see the videos images but instead all i get is this error
"GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/$%7Bvideo.snippet.thumbnails.high.url%7D 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: The problem is pretty obvious, when you look at that URL - `${video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}` has not been replaced by anything, the browser tries to fetch the _literal_ "URL" `${video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}` here. You need to use proper template literal syntax, for that sort of variable substitution to work - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what you mean by use proper template
can you give me example?

Comment: What for did I just link you to the explanation? _"Template literals are literals delimited with backtick (\`) characters, allowing for multi-line strings, string interpolation with embedded expressions, [...]"_

Comment: i check the link you sent but i still dont understand where exactly my problem is can you point where is my problem so i know what to look for?

Comment: The `${...}` does not get replaced with anything because you used `'` as string delimiters.

Comment: it took a lot of reading and trying but i managed to find my problem
i never used the backticks before so i couldnt find it on my keyboard xD
anyway thank you very much for your help